# Selecting an element created using document.createElement jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am creating  a number of div and ul elements using document.createElement. In a case, when I am creating these elements I need to take reference of one of those elements that I created above and assign it as the parent to element that's next in line to be created.

I have the id (e.g "idoftheelement") of the created element but when I do

```
    $('#idoftheelement')
```

I don't get the element.

Is there a possibility to get the element. If yes how ?

**Edit:**

Below is html structure I am trying to generate based on a JSON input data. Every element in the JSON array could have a child array of elements. All the elements will have the same markup and the difference is only in where they are getting placed. I have to construct this in a recursive way i.e for every JSON element check if child elements(and the child elements could also contain child elements) are present, if yes then i should append these child elements to corresponding parent thread block. This is why I need to know if there is a direct way to  get the reference of parent element that is in context to the current element so that It can be appended.

```
<div id="comment-12345">
<div id="threads-block-12345"
    <ul id="thread-12345">
        <li id="thread-item-12346">
            <div id="comment-12346">
                <div id="threads-block-12346"
                    <ul id="thread-12346">
                        <li id="thread-item-12347">
                            <!--keeps growing if there till all the children are processed-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="comment-xyz">
                <div id="threads-block-xyz"
                    <ul id="thread-xyz">
                        <li id="thread-item-xyz">
                            <!--keeps growing if there till all the children are processed-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: how are you "creating a number of divs" - need code

Comment: Why do you need to use the ID for this? Why not just keep the element in a variable and use it directly?

Comment: Have you appended the element before referencing it?

Comment: [3] Show us some code please

Comment: you have to use on to target dynamically added elements. and if you are using jquery you can use $("div").appendTo("some element") instead of document.createElement

Comment: your code is still not clear. you say json and all but doesnot show that code. anyways you can use :

.parent() for 1 level up parent,.parents("parentclass/id") for specific parent and .prev() to navigate up in this context

Answer (score 0):

The code `$('#idoftheelement')` tells me you are using jQuery, so you shouldn't be using `document.createElement`.  What you need to do is create the element using jQuery and reference it by that variable.  For example:

```
var $node = $("<div id='" + id + "'>")

$node.append( ... new elements ... )
```